# add class to last word

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is why the phrase is red. Should be only the word after `>`. The regular expression is correct ([here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/))

```
$(".some").html(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/([^>]*)$/, function (match) {
        return '<span class="red">' + match + '</span>';
    });
});

.red {
    color:#ff0000
}

<div class="some">RAW MATERIALS & CHEMICALS>Earth & Stone</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4cMN/1/

Comment: should be red only after thr last >

Comment: `>    >` does not mean start and end of the tag, and you are setting the color to the whole span where in the text is part of the span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to do this that is a bit nicer than the regex way. It is using the power of the DOM: it is therefore the way that the browser itself understand the webpage.

```
var textnode = $(".some").contents().last().get(0), // get the last node in .some
    last = textnode.splitText(textnode.data.lastIndexOf('>') + 1); // split it after the last >

$(last).wrap('<span class="red"/>'); // wrap the newly-created node in a span
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4cMN/11/

Note that this allows us to use the text data in a more intuitive way, rather than worrying about HTML encoding.

Answer (score 4):

`text` has special characters html encoded, so you should be looking for `&gt;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/Z4cMN/10/

```
$(".some").html(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/&gt;(.*)$/, function (match, title) {
        return '&gt;<span class="red">' + title + '</span>';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the HTML `&` and `>` are escaped. Try unescaping the characters before passing it to the regEx.

```
$(".some").html(function (i, text) {
    return htmlDecode(text).replace(/([^>]*)$/, function (match) {
        return '<span class="red">' + match + '</span>';
    });

    function htmlDecode(input) {
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.innerHTML = input;
        return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fptbd/